# Como usar "while not in" no Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loop, while

Eu tentei fazer um loop com o while para verificar se uma condição foi satisfeita. Se o usuário digitar 0, 1 ou 2 o programa deveria parar de perguntar ao usuário qual número ele vai escolher. Caso o usuário escolha um número diferente de 0, 1 ou 2, o programa irá perguntar para o usuário qual número ele quer escolher.

```
lista = [0, 1, 2]
usuario =''
while usuario not in lista:
    usuario = input('Escolha um número entre 0 e 2: ')
```

O comportamento que eu observei não foi o que eu esperava. Ao invés do programa parar de pedir para o usuário escolher um número quando ele digitar um número contido na lista, ele continuou a pedir para o usuário escolher um número. Eu achei que se o usuário escolhesse um número da lista o programa deveria parar. Alguém sabe dizer onde estou errando?

Também tentei fazer esse loop desta forma, mas tive o mesmo problema:

```
lista = [0, 1, 2]
usuario =''
while usuario != lista:
    usuario = input('Escolha um número entre 0 e 2: ')
```

P.S: Estou usando um Windows 7; Python 3.6.5 e o PyCharm.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

O erro é que a função `input` **sempre** retorna um texto e você está verificando se um texto pertence a uma lista de inteiros. Esta condição jamais será satisfeita.

```
print('1' in [0, 1, 2])  # False
```

Se você quer verificar se um inteiro pertence a uma lista de inteiros, precisa fazer a conversão:

```
while usuario not in lista:
    usuario = int(input('Escolha um número entre 0 e 2: '))
```

Assim, `usuario` também será um inteiro e quando o usuário entrar com um valor da lista, a condição será satisfeita.

Como comentado, isso pode gerar uma exceção `ValueError` caso o usuário entrar com algo que não seja um número. Para prevenir isso, basta utilizar o `try/except`:

```
while usuario not in lista:
    try:
        usuario = int(input('Escolha um número entre 0 e 2: '))
    except ValueError:
        print('Por favor, entre com um número')
```

Ainda, se o objetivo é apenas fazer a leitura de um valor entre 0 e 2, você não precisa definir uma lista para isso, basta fazer a condição `0 <= usuario <= 2`. Por exemplo:

```
while True
    try:
        usuario = int(input('Escolha um número entre 0 e 2: '))
        if not 0 <= usuario <= 2:
            raise ValueError('Número deve estar entre 0 e 2')
        break
    except ValueError as error:
        print(error)
```

Comment: Era isso mesmo, obrigada.

Answer (score 3):

Uma solução simples, e que evita os erros já mencionados como `ValueError` no caso de tentar converter um caracter não numerico para int, seria validar se o input é um digito, ou seja, se o que o usuário digitou converte para inteiro.

```
lista = [0, 1, 2]

while True:
    usuario = input('Escolha um número entre 0 e 2: ')
    if usuario.isdigit() and int(usuario) in lista:
        break
```

Comment: É uma boa solução também. Neste caso, `usuario` ficaria sendo uma *string*, o que dependendo do problema pode ser interessante.

Comment: Sim, sim... Mas até ai é tranquilo né, uma vez validado que é digito, em seguida ja pode fazer a conversão sem medo de ser feliz.

Comment: Pode ser até reduzido para `if int(usuario) in lista: ...`, visto que pela pergunta e a resposta aceite do Anderson não ser preciso que tratar/prevenir exceções devido ao input poder ser letras

Answer (score 1):

O problema é que usuario vai voltar como uma string, tenta escrever

```
 while usuario not in lista:
      usuario = input('Escolha um número entre 0 e 2: ')
      if(regex(usuario)
           usuario = int(usuario)
      else 
         print('Digite um Numero')
```

Comment: Eu tentei isso, mas ele retorna um erro: "ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ' '"

Comment: é, isso vai acontencer sempre que o usuario digitar algo que não é passivel de conversão para um inteiro, como uma letra ou um espaço vazio. Uma solução é usar uma expressão regular para ver se o input é um numero.