# Repetir uma pergunta errada até o usuário responder a pergunta com uma informação configurada

Tags: python

```
import pandas as pd 
import os 

quarto = 4
quinto = 5
sexto = 6
sétimo = 7
oitavo = 8
nono = 9

primeiro = 1
segundo  = 2
terceiro = 3

tabela_séries = [['Quarto Ano', 'Ensino fundamental I', 'Digite 4'],
            ["Quinto Ano","Ensino fundamental I","Digite 5"],
            ['Sexto Ano', 'Ensino fundametal II', 'Digite 6'],
            ["Sétimo Ano","Ensino fundamental II","Digite 7"],
            ['Oitavo Ano', 'Ensino fundamental II', 'Digite 8'],
            ["Nono Ano","Ensino fundamental II","Digite 9"],
            ["","","",],
            ['Primeiro Ano', 'Ensinoo Médio ', 'Digite 1'],
            ["Segundo Ano", "Ensino Médio","Digite 2"],
            ['Terceiro Ano', 'Ensino Médio', 'Digite 3']]


df = pd.DataFrame(tabela_séries, columns=['', '', ''])

per_série = int(input(f"{df}   ----> em qual série você está?:"))

while per_série != nono or oitavo or sétimo or sexto or quinto or quarto or primeiro or segundo or terceiro:
    per_série = int(input(f"{df}   ----> em qual série você está?:"))

if per_série == nono:
    print("Deu Certo!")
```

quando inicio esse código posso errar varias vezes mas após inserir "nono" que é a resposta ele não mostra o "deu certo"

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Answer (score -1):

A condição do `while` está errada.

Seguindo a mesma linha de raciocínio que você usou, teria que repetir a comparação em cada `or`, ou seja:

```py
while per_série != nono or per_série != oitavo or per_série != sétimo or per_série != sexto or per_série != quinto or per_série != quarto or per_série != primeiro or per_série != segundo or per_série != terceiro:
    per_série = int(input(f"{df}   ----> em qual série você está?:"))
```

Como todas as comparações envolvem a variável `per_serie`, é possível encurtar essa linha usando o comando `not in`:

```py
while per_série not in [nono, oitavo, sétimo, sexto, quinto, quarto, primeiro, segundo, terceiro]:
    per_série = int(input(f"{df}   ----> em qual série você está?:"))
```

([Aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/300965/como-usar-while-not-in-no-python) tem uma pergunta no pt.stackoverflow sobre o comando `in` e `not in`)

Porém, observando atentamente o valor das variáveis, elas são simplesmente os números inteiros de 1 a 9, então é possível encurtar ainda mais:

```py
while per_série < 1 or per_série > 9:
    per_série = int(input(f"{df}   ----> em qual série você está?:"))
```